# Why my map of pointer to function isn't compiling?

Tags: c++

I have this class :

```
class TaskManager
{
public:
  TaskManager();
  ~TaskManager();

  using taskFunction = void (TaskManager::*)(BabelPacket const &);
  void executeTask(Task const &task);
  void signInTask(BabelPacket const &);
  void signUpTask(BabelPacket const &);
  void signOutTask(BabelPacket const &);
  std::map<unsigned int, taskFunction> actions =
   {
     {BabelPacket::Code::SIGN_IN, &TaskManager::signInTask},
     {BabelPacket::Code::SIGN_UP, &TaskManager::signUpTask},
     {BabelPacket::Code::SIGN_OUT, &TaskManager::signOutTask},
  };
}
```

And this is my enum

```
struct      BabelPacket
{
  // Code enum
  enum struct   Code : unsigned int
  {
    NONE = 00,
    // Requests
    SIGN_IN = 100,
    SIGN_UP = 101,
    SIGN_OUT = 102,
  }
}
```

But when I compile this I got :

```
   includes/TaskManager.hpp:38: error: could not convert ‘{{SIGN_IN, &TaskManager::signInTask}, {SIGN_UP, &TaskManager::signUpTask}, {SIGN_OUT, &TaskManager::signOutTask}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<unsigned int, void (TaskManager::*)(const BabelPacket&)>’
       };
   ^
```

Got an idea why ?

Comment: Since you use `enum struct`, I don't think you can initialize the `unsigned int` key from enum members without casting them.

Comment: Note all uppercase constants is antipattern in C++

Comment: change `std::map<unsigned int,` to `std::map<BabelPacket::Code,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your enum is a `class enum`, it is not automatically convertible to `int`. Either make a regular enum out of it, our use static_cast, or use `BabelPacket::Code` as your map index type.